# CDATA not working on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the below xml's in my code

XML Parsing Error: not well-formed

Location: http://localhost:3000/api/client?client=test1

Line Number 1, Column 1111:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application>
 <name><![CDATA[TESTapp2]]></name>
 <application-identifier>wac-8c28afa4-0f6e-11e1-8885-7071bc62c7bc</application-identifier>
<clients>
  <pricepoint id="1" name=<![CDATA[TEST-price]]> currency="dollar" locale="la" country="india" price="50" text="this is a TEST" receipt="oi120934" operator-reference="1213w" operator-id="1"></pricepoint></pricepoints><product-image></product-image>
</clients>
</application>

 <name><![CDATA[TESTapp2]]></name> this is working 
 <name=\"[CDATA[TESTapp2]]\"> this is not working,throws encoding error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, Using CDATA as an attribute value is forbidden. CDATA can only be used for text nodes.